# Innovation HTTP Client - How do I set SSL to accept all server certificates?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I plan to connect via HTTPS to a server using the Innovation HTTP Client.

I need to be able to accept all server SSL certificates.

There are some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292799/basic-authentication-with-https?rq=1) using HttpsURLConnection, but I need to use the Innovation implementation.

Does anyone have any examples for [Innovation HTTP Client](http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/)?

Comment: Library link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Innovation HTTPClient doesn't directly support HTTPS.  See [this page on the Innovation website](http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/https.html) for more information.  There are a number of 3rd party patches and examples listed there which you can implement.  Setting certificate acceptance depends on the patch implementation you choose.

**EDIT / UPDATE**

Note that `JSSE SSL` implementation is being used and the intent is to define a `TrustedManager` and bind it via `SSLContext` to `HTTPConnection`.

Assuming you know how to create a `TrustManager`, the following code is co-opted from [this Stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android#1000205), which also shows how to generate one.

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { ... };

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
```

Per the README file I got from the JSSE SSL download off the Innovation website link from earlier, you can assign it to the HTTPConnection by doing this:

```
    // Attach context to connection via socket factory
    HTTPConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

} catch (Exception e) { ... }
```